# Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Using Dirichlet Test, it can be shown that the it uniformly converges for $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\{0\}$.

In $x=0$ there is obviously a pointwise convergence to 0.

However, I'm struggling to make a conclusion for $\mathbb{R}$.

If you could help me find a conclusion or provide another direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a different case for $x=0$ when applying Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence?

Comment: @ClementC. For $x=0$ the sequence $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$ does not converge to 0 as required by the test.

Comment: But then... take $f_n(x) = (-1)^{n-1}$ (partial sums are uniformly bounded) and $g_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$ and apply the test.

Comment: @ClementC.That only shows pointwise convergence in $x=0$. You need to pick one sequence for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Which is what I did. I don't understand your comment -- see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short:** *here, you shouldn't have to worry about $0$ in the first place.*

When you apply the Dirichlet test, take
$$
a_n(x) = (-1)^{n-1}, \qquad b_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\geq 1$. Then

- For $M\stackrel{\rm def}{=} 1$, we have
  $$
  \left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^N a_n(x) \right\rvert \leq M
  $$
  for all $N\geq 1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
- For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\geq 1$,
  $$
  b_n(x) \geq b_{n+1}(x)
  $$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty }\lVert b_n\rVert_\infty = 0$ (uniform convergence of $b_n$ to $0$)

Therefore, the (Uniform) Dirichlet test guarantees that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x)b_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$
converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you explain why is it monotonic?

Comment: @AshuvHalim The second condition? Because $b_{n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}b_n(x)\geq 0$ and $1+x^2\geq 1$.

Comment: How do you show uniform convergence of $b_n$ to $0$? That's what I meant. Sorry.

Comment: @AshuvHalim If you differentiate $b_n$ to study it, you see it achieves its maximum when $x^2 = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$. This gives $$\lVert b_n\rVert_\infty = b_n(1/\sqrt{2(n-1)}) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\right)^n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0\cdot \frac{1}{e^{1/2}} = 0$$

Comment: @AshuvHalim Did that clear things up?

Comment: Yes. That was very helpful. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @AshuvHalim You're welcome!

Comment: @ClementC. Actually, $||b_n||_{\infty}=b_n(1/\sqrt{n-1})$.   But your conclusion holds.  (+1) ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola You're right, turns out differentiating it hard.

Comment: @ClementC. ... not as hard as adding and multiplying ...

Answer (score 1):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
S_N(x)&=&\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}\\
&=&\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\frac{1-\frac{(-1)^N}{(1+x^2)^{N}}}{1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=x^2\frac{1-\frac{(-1)^N}{(1+x^2)^{N}}}{x^2+2}\\
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|S_N(x)-\frac{x^2}{x^2+2}\right|&=&\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{N}(x^2+2)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ f_N(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x)^{N}(x+2)}, x\ge0. $$
Solveing $f'(x)=0$ gives $x=x_N\equiv\frac{\sqrt{N^2+1}-N+1}{N}$ and noting $f_N''(x_N)<0$. Therefore $f_N(x)$ attains the max at $x=x_N$. Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\max\left|S_N(x)-\frac{x^2}{x^2+2}\right|=\max f_N(x^2)=\max_{x\ge0}f_N(x)\\
&=&f_N(x_N)=\frac{\sqrt{N^2+1}-N+1}{\sqrt{N^2+1}+N+1}\left(\frac{N}{\sqrt{N^2+1}+1}\right)^N\\
&\le&\frac{\sqrt{N^2+1}-N+1}{\sqrt{N^2+1}+N+1}\\
&\le&\frac{2}{\sqrt{N^2+1}+N+1}\\
&\to&0
\end{eqnarray}
as $N\to\infty$ and thence $\{S_N(x)\}$ converges uniformly to $\frac{x^2}{x^2+2}$.

Comment: (+1) for the brute force approach.